# Import Tensor flow library error

Tags: tensorflow, import

After debugging, I found that below strange error

Program: (only 1 line)
import tensorflow as tf

When I run above code first time, I got below warning:
\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters

=> From web, this is just an warning and can ignore it ( i guess)

When I rerun the same code, I got below error

File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "H:/Python/Test/Test.py", line 15, in 
    import tensorflow as tf

File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import

File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 121, in 
    from tensorflow.python.platform import test

File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\test.py", line 65, in 
    tf_export('test.mock')(mock)

File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\tf_export.py", line 96, in **call**
    (undecorated_func.**name**, undecorated_func._tf_api_names))

SymbolAlreadyExposedError: Symbol unittest.mock is already exposed as ('test.mock',).

Now I need to restart the kernel in order to run through the whole source code.  Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I tried this way and it worked (no more kernel restart is needed for further execution):

1/ Open the file `test.py` from this link:

> "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\test.py"

2/ Comment the line 65: `#tf_export('test.mock')(mock)`

Comment: Yes, I think so. Afaik, this mock test is just unit test for the TF framework itself, hence, commenting this causes no harm to further execution (at least until tf v1.10 that i'm using).